# Does sneaking slowly produce less sound than sneaking regularily?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When sneaking, you are able to move slowly using <kbd>Shift</kbd> as when walking. But, are NPCs more likely to hear you if you are sneaking "fast"? Does sneaking slowly actually reduce the sound you make?

I couldn't determine any effects of sneaking slowly or regularily, the guards always seem to not hear me, regardless of how I sneak.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it does.

How enemies detect you while sneaking is based on multiple factors, including

- Visibility
- Noise Level

The noise level again depends on multiple factors, including the type of armour you're wearing, and your movement speed.

Sneaking slowly and sneaking quickly change your movement speeds, and hence, change the noise you produce.

[SOURCE](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sneak#Remaining_Undetected)