# Does weapon weight affect sneaking detection?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

This is an extension of [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106918/when-should-i-enchant-with-muffle-instead-of-sneak/) that I don't wish to necro. Does the category of "equipped items" - whose weight affect noise - include weapons? Searching around, I have found that weapon category, not weight, affect noise made by weapon swings. One person have said that weapon weight affects noise when drawn. However, I have seen nothing about whether weapon weight affects noise by simply equipping it, undrawn.

To summarise: Is a Dragonbone Sword noisier than an Iron Sword? Does it matter if it's sheathed, drawn or swinging?

Bonus marks: Is a power attack noisier while sneaking? Also, I know Dagger is more silent than other 1H which are more silent than 2H, but is there a difference in Sword/Axe/Mace noise, all else being equal?

Thanks for answering this question on an old but always-relevant ES game ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While [swinging the weapon makes noise](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sneak), no. Weapon weight has literally nothing to do with your ability to remain undetected, provided you aren't chopping the air into pieces as you stealth about.

Daggers are silent, **anything** bigger makes a detectable noise.

Answer (score 2):

An aspect of your question that is not touched on by the other answer is the effect that a weapon may have on stealth by being unsheathed.

- Prior to acquiring the Sneak perk `Silence`, movement of your feet affects your ability to stay in stealth.
- When you have a weapon drawn, your character will keep his/her back to the camera.  So looking around the corner with your camera will involve the shuffling of feet while your weapons are drawn.

As such I've found that Hit & Run (& Hide) tactics can be assisted by either sheathing my weapons or by keeping my camera still.

---

I'm incurably nosy, so the weapons get sheathed.